# NPM -v not showing version in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

I wish to run `npm audit` and `npm audit fix`

In my package.json npm is version 6.4.1

`"npm": "^6.4.1",`

But when I run `npm -v` in the project directory it shows 5.6.0

When I run `npm install npm@latest -g` it shows npm@6.4.1

The when I run `npm -v` in the project directory it shows 5.6.0

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: you may just need to open a new terminal window. What os are you on? installation issues are pretty tightly tied to operating system.

Comment: Hi, I'm on OSx, I tried opening a new terminal but still sames the same, also tried cleaning the cache but it still insists on the version being 5.6.0

Comment: You may have two versions of node installed, and a mixed up PATH. Did you install node from homebrew and/or the nodejs website? Side note: you don't typically need to specify which npm to use in your project folder, it's assumed that if you have a package.json, npm will be able to interpret it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the latest version of node resolves the `npm -v` version conflict.

This is due to `npm` being installed during the `node` install and therefore fixing any conflict with the global installation path.

[image]